# using my inflater with multiple view, making app slow : (

Tags: android, if-statement, android-fragments, layout-inflater

```
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_MENU_NUMBER = "menu_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MENU_NUMBER);


        if (i == 0){
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodmenu, container, true);

             return getView();
             //급식
            }

        else if (i == 1)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable, container, true);
             return getView();
             //수련회

        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable, container, true);
             return getView();
             //시간표
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable, container, true);
             return getView();
             //가정통신문
        }
        else if (i == 4)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable, container, true);
             return getView();
             //연간학사일정
        }
        else if (i == 5)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.yearevent, container, true);
             return getView();
            // 학교홈페이지
        }
        else if (i == 6)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable, container, true);
             return getView();
             // 주번활동
        }
```

this is my program, using inflater with multiple view, and it keep makes my app slow, any suggestions? thanks : )

Comment: View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable, container, true); return v;

Comment: It crashesㅜㅜ Doesn't even open : (

Comment: 05-18 17:31:16.302: E/SELinux(12344): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
05-18 17:31:16.302: E/SELinux(12344):  
05-18 17:31:16.302: E/SELinux(12344): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SHV-E330K_4.3_0024
05-18 17:31:16.302: E/SELinux(12344):  
05-18 17:31:16.302: E/SELinux(12344):  
05-18 17:31:16.302: E/SELinux(12344): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts

Comment: these are the red ones